# Interface Implementation Issue

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, interface

I Have a Base Interface Like this

```
public interface IHRMISBaseConnector
    {
         IHRMISEmployeeConnector EmployeeConnector { get  ; set; }  
    }
```

And i have one more interface like this

```
public  interface IHRMISEmployeeConnector
    {
        String Add(EmployeeDetails e);
        Boolean Update(EmployeeDetails e);
        Boolean Delete(int id);
    }
```

I want implement  IHRMISBaseConnector in this class DDWEDocumentOperations

How can i implement ? Please let me know if anybody knows it

Comment: You can comment on the answers to this question, asking for help or clarification. Please don't edit their answer for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help you:

```
class FakeImplementationOfEmployeeConnector : IHRMISEmployeeConnector
{
    public string Add(EmployeeDetails e)
    {
        //...
    }

    public bool Update(EmployeeDetails e)
    {
        //...
    }

    public bool Delete(int id)
    {
        //...
    }
}

class DDWEDocumentOperations : IHRMISBaseConnector
{
    IHRMISEmployeeConnector employeeConnector = new FakeImplementationOfEmployeeConnector();

    public IHRMISEmployeeConnector EmployeeConnector
    {
        get
        {
            return employeeConnector;
        }
        set
        {
            employeeConnector = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
    public class DDWEDocumentOperations : IHRMISBaseConnector
    {
        private IHRMISEmployeeConnector _employeeConnector;

        public IHRMISEmployeeConnector EmployeeConnector
        {
            get { return _employeeConnector; }
            set { _employeeConnector = value; }
        }
    }
```